# GetStream.io get the total count of the posts in a feed

Tags: flutter, kotlin, getstream-io

How can I get the total count of the all posts in a feed?
Also how can I count all post where an extraField is set?

like: moderated=true

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't count the total posts in a feed unless you keep the count on your end. Stream has a default maximum returned activities before you need to paginate them.

Same goes for the question regarding the extra field.

The default is 25 but it can be increased to 100 with a { limit : 100 } parameter in the feed.get() API call.